# My Ubuntu 15.04 wireless connection is ridiculously slow!

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu OS from 12.04 to 15.04 on my Samsung R580 laptop. I have been experiencing issues with my wireless connection. My wired connection is working perfectly and my other devices(phone, ps3, etc.) are working well on the same wireless connection. I am fairly new to Ubuntu and would appreciate some help on this topic. Thanks!

output for "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8192] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7160]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl819xE
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: i updated my question with the output of that command @Pilot6